# AOP is failing while build sbt assembly

Tags: scala, sbt, aop

I am trying to build sbt code. I am using `sbt assembly` but it is breaking at `Aop`. Used following [MergeStragegy](https://gist.github.com/colestanfield/fac042d3108b0c06e952) for Aop
Following is the error log

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
    /home/puneet/repo/target/streams/_global/assemblyOption/_global/streams/assembly/sbtMergeTarget-e2e021ed2f7893685f6d16c35a11a6d2dcda6205.tmp[error] org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: -//AspectJ//DTD//EN; systemId: http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 2; The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed.
    [error]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    [error]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    [error]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
    [error]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    [error]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1473)
    [error]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanDecls(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:2044)
    [error]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanDTDExternalSubset(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:307)
    [error]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1174)
    [error]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1045)
    [error]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:959)
    [error]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    [error]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    [error]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    [error]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    [error]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    [error]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    [error]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    [error]     at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    [error]     at scala.xml.factory.XMLLoader.loadXML(XMLLoader.scala:41)
    [error]     at scala.xml.factory.XMLLoader.loadXML$(XMLLoader.scala:37)
    [error]     at scala.xml.XML$.loadXML(XML.scala:60)
    [error]     at scala.xml.factory.XMLLoader.loadFile(XMLLoader.scala:48)
    [error]     at scala.xml.factory.XMLLoader.loadFile$(XMLLoader.scala:48)
    [error]     at scala.xml.XML$.loadFile(XML.scala:60)
    [error]     at AopMerge$.$anonfun$apply$1(AopMerge.scala:17)
    [error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    [error]     at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    [error]     at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    [error]     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
    [error]     at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
    [error]     at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
    [error]     at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
    [error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    [error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
    [error]     at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    [error]     at AopMerge$.apply(AopMerge.scala:17)
    [error]     at sbtassembly.MergeStrategy.apply(MergeStrategy.scala:20)
    [error]     at sbtassembly.Assembly$.applyStrategy$1(Assembly.scala:110)
    [error]     at sbtassembly.Assembly$.$anonfun$applyStrategies$11(Assembly.scala:135)
    [error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    [error]     at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:941)
    [error]     at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:941)
    [error]     at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1429)
    [error]     at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:74)
    [error]     at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:73)
    [error]     at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:56)
    [error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
    [error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
    [error]     at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    [error]     at sbtassembly.Assembly$.applyStrategies(Assembly.scala:132)
    [error]     at sbtassembly.Assembly$.x$1$lzycompute$1(Assembly.scala:25)
    [error]     at sbtassembly.Assembly$.x$1$1(Assembly.scala:23)
    [error]     at sbtassembly.Assembly$.stratMapping$lzycompute$1(Assembly.scala:23)
    [error]     at sbtassembly.Assembly$.stratMapping$1(Assembly.scala:23)
    [error]     at sbtassembly.Assembly$.inputs$lzycompute$1(Assembly.scala:68)
    [error]     at sbtassembly.Assembly$.inputs$1(Assembly.scala:58)
    [error]     at sbtassembly.Assembly$.apply(Assembly.scala:85)
    [error]     at sbtassembly.Assembly$.$anonfun$assemblyTask$1(Assembly.scala:244)
    [error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
    [error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
    [error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:67)
    [error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:281)
    [error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:19)
    [error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:290)
    [error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:281)
    [error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
    [error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
    [error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    [error]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    [error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    [error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    [error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    [error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    [error] (repo / assembly) org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: -//AspectJ//DTD//EN; systemId: http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 2; The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed.
```

Last week the same changes where working. But somehow it is throwing this error. What could be the reason?

sbt version -> `1.3.10`

I have created a new MergeStrategy for aop.xml files (part of the Kamon dependencies).

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. It seems like the "https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd" file has changed

Comment: @omer I replaced http with https in this line https://gist.github.com/colestanfield/fac042d3108b0c06e952#file-gistfile1-scala-L9 and it worked for me

Comment: Like I said in [my comment on AspectJ issue #191](https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/issues/191#issuecomment-1296204706), the DTD has not changed.

Answer (score 1):

If [replacing http with https does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74158534/aop-is-failing-while-build-sbt-assembly#comment131076832_74158534), it might be worth trying disabling DTD validation as follows:

```scala
    import java.io.FileInputStream
    import org.xml.sax.InputSource

    val parser = {
      val factory = javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance()
      factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false)
      factory.newSAXParser()
    }
    val xmls: Seq[Elem] = files.map(f => XML.loadXML(new InputSource(new FileInputStream(f)), parser))
```